# C++ Linker Error Undefined reference in Singleton class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, linker-errors

I'm trying to port this java singleton class to c++:

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton uniqueInstance;

private Singleton() {} 
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (uniqueInstance == null) {
        uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
    }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }
}
```

I ported to this C++ code:

```
class Singleton {
private:
  Singleton() {
    cout << "new Singleton is called" << endl;
  }
  static Singleton* uniqueInstance;
public:
   static Singleton* getInstance() {
    if (!uniqueInstance) {
      uniqueInstance = new Singleton();
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
  }
};
```

But I can't compile this! and gcc linker error occurred.

Comment: Please show exactly what the linker error was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you define the `static` member outside the declaration:

```
Singleton* Singleton::uniqueInstance = nullptr;
```

Comment: You should initialise to nullptr too.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Why? My program was complied without error without using nullptr!

Comment: @Khajavi Also without high optimisation? Pointers are not guarenteed to be zero on initialisation.

Comment: In C++11 you should not use pointers. New standard ensures initialization of static member variables is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your cpp file probably does not reserve space for the static instance, you need to add
 `Singelton* Singleton::uniqueInstance = NULL;` to your cpp file and then allocate it in the first call